# How to configure Python env for Xcode 4?

Tags: python, xcode, autocomplete

I would like to configure my Xcode 4.3 environment to use Python with auto-complete. E.g. if I type import numpy Xcode would be able to complete numpy.

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Unlike Xcode 3.2, Xcode 4.x does not have support for Python projects.

You can get around most of the missing functionality by using a project template (e.g., https://github.com/chenhaiteng/Python-Project-Template-for-Xcode-4). But there are a few things you can't deal with that way, including auto-complete. (You also can't run a Python debugger, etc.)